# buscador que se activa al dar click en el icono de buscar

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

tengo un buscador que se **activa al dar click en el icono de buscar y se desactiva al dar click en cualquier parte de la página**, quiero desactivar esa animación, es decir quiero dejar el buscador fijo como cualquier página sin que los usuarios tengan que dar click en el botón para que les aparezca el buscador,
esta es la función que tiene pero no logro desactivarla

```
function(c) {return a.call(b.src, b.listener, c)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el evento .onkeyup en tu input de búsqueda, y cada vez que se ejecute el evento llames a tu function
Aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de búsqueda de nombres de una tabla usando el evento .onkeyup

```js
document.getElementById("buscador").onkeyup = function() {functionBuscar()};
function functionBuscar() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("buscador");
  filtro = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filtro) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="buscador"  placeholder="Buscardor" title="Buscar nombres">

<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th >Nombre</th>
    <th >Apellido</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fernando</td>
    <td>Torrico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dilan</td>
    <td>Menese</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Otro nombre</td>
    <td>su apellido</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```